# Adding redux to angular & ionic project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, redux

Setting up an Angular + Ionic project, we're trying to include Redux into the story. We have a working angular-ionic setup. When trying to add Redux using the following steps:

```
npm install --save ng-redux
```

and include in app index.js file

```
import ngRedux from 'ng-redux';
```

to finally inject into angular app:

```
const app = angular
.module('app', [
    ngRedux,
    'ionic',
    components,
])
```

makes the last step result in app crash: "Failed to instantiate module {} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: add ngRedux as string in angular dependencies
(+ if you're using eslint: disable lint on ngRedux import statement)

```
const app = angular
.module('app', [
    'ngRedux',
    'ionic',
    components,
])
```